Is it safe to live in a home with a blocked water heater flue?
So, not my home, but I'm in an older home with two other apartment units, and one of the units had mentioned that they haven't had hot water since last Friday, making it 6 days now. Their unit has a gas bill and gas payment, so the Gas company was by here yesterday to try and fix the problem. The only way into the water heater is through the basement in our unit, so obviously they needed in.
After some work, they said they couldn't fix the issue, given that the water heater venting or exhausting system "wasn't up to code." They attached a Danger/Warning label to the exhaust/vent pipe and left. I've been working on getting in touch with my landlord (he's on vacation) to fix the situation, but my bigger question is, is the unit safe to live in at this point?
I'm guessing there must be some blockage or something preventing proper ventilation for the water heater exhaust/vent pipe, but would this cause a gas buildup or potential leak throughout the home? I'm not going to try and fix the issue myself, but I'm just wondering if my girlfriend and I should remain in this unit or live somewhere else while this is going on.
Any additional information I can provide please just let me know. Thanks!

"Not up to code" doesn't necessarily mean "blocked". There isn't enough detail here to answer, and even if there was it's somewhat subjective. VTC.

if it's winter and they have no heating probably it's not safe, but that is a legal question not home improvement.

A blocked/non functioning vent is very bad.  Bad as going to sleep and never waking up bad.  There should be CO detectors in that building.  Quite a few locations have it as a law they are to be installed.  Ontario instated that law after a family of five were found dead in their beds.
If the gas people slap a warning/"Red Tag" on it, They should have blocked/locked out the gas flow to that heater, so it cannot be used.  There should be a valve turned sideways to the gas line going to the unit, if off.
If they did not, the pilot light is still on, the unit still tries/comes on, Call the local fire department now.

With the faulty heater turned off, you're safe.
For your neighbour if it's winter and they have no heating probably it's not safe, but that is a legal question not home improvement.

If it's winter they should be provided with multiple electric resistive heaters until the gas is restored.
